# Memory leak - Javascript/jquery and canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, canvas, memory-leaks

I got one serious problem, concerning a canvas carousel. I decided, as a first html/canvas/javascript approach, to try to make myself some picture carousel.

You can find it here, on everypage of my homepage http://www.wizopunk-art.com
I deactivated the carousel, so just...

```
var wizopunk = new backroundViewer("backgroundCanv");
```

..somewhere in your console

As you might sens right away, the animation isn't very effective.. It seems I got some kind of memory leak, but I'm unable to find it on my own.. I was hoping you might have some hint, like usefull tools or even if somebody want to throw an eye in my own script.. I got the impression that each picture I draw on the canvas is kept in memory..

here the link to the script : 
http://www.wizopunk-art.com/javascript/carousel.js

I don't know if my description is precise enough, and I don't mean to bother or something.. so please just tell me if I'm missing something in my message

PS : sorry for my poor english..

Answer (score 0):

First... a better way of creating a rendering loop is using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`. Another thing is rendering everything in background first. Overe here you can find quite many performance tips on developing with the canvas element. (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer !

So I changed all my setTimout into requestAnimationFrame (found a little script for normalizing). Nothing really changed.. 

I readed the content of your link, quite interesting, but excepting the "requestAnimationFrame", I already tried everything :)

I have a buffer canvas.. I'm just beggining to wonder that maybe my pictures are too big and too heavy to be draw in such animations ?